# How to prevent changing the original object when its reference changes?

Tags: php, reference, pass-by-reference

In the following snippet, `$sd` is a `DateTime` object. It is assigned to a variable called `$a`. On calling `add` on `$a`, `$sd` also changes.

```
$sd = new DateTime();
$a = $sd;
$a->add(new DateInterval("P1M")); // Add 1 month to $a
```

This happens because `$a` was a reference to `$sd`. Is there a way, where `$sd` doesn't change? What should be the approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clone`

```
$sd = new DateTime();
$a = clone $sd;
$a->add(new DateInterval("P1M")); // Add 1 month to $a
```